# PSQL asking for Unique constraint?

Tags: foreign-keys, psql, unique-constraint, composite-primary-key

So I am trying to create the following tables and `psql` will not let me create these tables unless `C_Subject` is given a `UNIQUE` constraint in the `Curriculum_Subjects` table.

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Curriculum(
      CID SERIAL NOT NULL,
      Curriculum_Name VARCHAR(100),
      Classes_Needed INTEGER,
      Classes_Total INTEGER,
      PRIMARY KEY(CID)
    );


   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Class_Subjects(
      C_Subject SERIAL NOT NULL,
      Class_Subject VARCHAR(100),
      PRIMARY KEY(C_Subject)
    );


    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Curriculum_Subjects(
      C_Subject SERIAL UNIQUE NOT NULL REFERENCES Class_Subjects(C_Subject),    
      CID SERIAL NOT NULL REFERENCES Curriculum(CID),
      PRIMARY KEY(C_Subject, CID)
    );
```

However the way I want my database to work is that one `C_Subject` can be in many curriculum. So below inserting the same `C_Subject` into two different curriculum should be valid. `CID` being the identifier for a different curriculum.

```
INSERT INTO Curriculum_Subjects(C_Subject, CID)
    VALUES(2,1);

INSERT INTO Curriculum_Subjects(C_Subject, CID)
    VALUES(2,2);
```

`psql` won't let this insert happen because `C_Subject` has a `UNIQUE` constraint. Why does `C_Subject` need to be `UNIQUE` in `Curriculum_Subjects` if it belongs to the composite key,  `PRIMARY KEY(C_Subject, CID)` ? Can this insert be achievable?

Comment: what error you get when "psql will not let me create these tables unless C_Subject is given a UNIQUE constraint in the Curriculum_Subjects table."?..

Comment: It's unlikely that you want the Curriculum_Subjects columns to be serial, because the values are generated by the serial key columns they reference.

Comment: Please give us some [mcve]s generating your errors.